# In C#.Net, Primary key is set for DataTable, yet exception 'Table doesn't have a primary key' is thrown

Tags: c#, datatable, primary-key, datacolumn

The precise exception is 
'System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Table doesn't have a primary key.

However, I have set the primary key. This is the code. Thanks.

```
DataColumn[] PrimaryKeyColumns; //Global
DataTable firstLinesDT = new DataTable();
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "FirstLines";
column.Unique = true;
firstLinesDT.Columns.Add(column);

PrimaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
PrimaryKeyColumns[0] = column;
firstLinesDT.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;  

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.ColumnName = "Length";
firstLinesDT.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "FilePath";
firstLinesDT.Columns.Add(column);

**// EXCEPTION THROWN AT FIND OPERATION** 
DataRow foundRow = firstLinesDT.NewRow();
foundRow = firstLinesDT.Rows.Find(line);
```

And according to msdn, this exactly how the primary key is supposed to be set-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx

Comment: This doesn't really help you figure out the problem, but the code as given worked for me.  It did not throw an exception on the Find call.

Comment: What .net version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and PrimaryKey.Length was 0  because I was declaring the Primary keys array before I filled the `DataTable` with rows from the adapter. Try to fill it with data first

Comment: Good job. You can add a full code snippet so that the questioner will get across with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe you don't add the primary key until all of the other columns are set.

In other words move `firstLinesDT.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;` to be after the point where you add the `FilePath` column.

Comment: Well, I tried that in the beginning, it didn't work and then I shifted my code and it looks like the code above. Bottom Line -> Both don't work :|

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question as your code does not include a `DataView`, it's possible that you left it out as you didn't think it was important in the example.

However, turning a table into a DataView, and then back `ToTable()`, removes the PrimaryKey.